# Multiple variables of different types in one line in Go (without short variable declaration syntax)

Tags: go

I was wondering if there's a way with Go to declare and initialise multiple variables of different types in one line without using the short declaration syntax `:=`.

Declaring for example two variables of the same type is possible:

```golang
var a, b string = "hello", "world"
```

Declaring variables of different types with the `:=` syntax is also possible:

```golang
c, d, e := 1, 2, "whatever"
```

This gives me an error instead:

```golang
var f int, g string = 1, "test"
```

Of course I'd like to keep the type otherwise I can just use the `:=` syntax.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any examples so I'm assuming this is just not possible?

If not, anyone knows if there's a plan to introduce such syntax in future releases?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's possible if you omit the type:

```
var i, s = 2, "hi"
fmt.Println(i, s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/A8oVANLTQn)):

```
2 hi
```

Note that the [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) is exactly a shorthand for this:

> A *short variable declaration* uses the syntax:
>
> ```
> ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .
> ```
>
> It is shorthand for a regular [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) with initializer expressions but no types:
>
> ```
> "var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .
> ```

Without omitting the type it's not possible, because the syntax of the [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) is:

```
VarSpec = IdentifierList ( Type [ "=" ExpressionList ] | "=" ExpressionList ) .
```

(There is only one optional type for an identifier list with an expression list.)

Also I assume you don't count this as 1 line (which otherwise is valid syntax, but gofmt breaks it into multiple lines):

```
var (i int = 2; s string = "hi")
```

Also if you only want to be able to explicitly state the types, you may provide them on the right side:

```
var i, s = int(2), string("hi")
```

But all in all, just use 2 lines for 2 different types, nothing to lose, readability to win.

Comment: Yep, I knew that but of course I'd like to keep the type explicit otherwise I can just use the `:=` syntax and get it over with =)

Comment: You can enforce types with conversions. var i, s = int(2), string("hi").

Comment: @StephenWeinberg that is something I could live with, I'd have both readability and explicit types in one line, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but it isn't very idiomatic. Everyone who knows Go well knows that 2 is an int and "hi" is a string unless the type is defined elsewhere. I would reject that in a code review.

Comment: All in all, just use 2 lines for 2 different types, it's not like you lose anything by it... It's actually more readable anyway...

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Will just wait a bit before accepting any answer just to see if someone comes up with something different. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't exactly specific to the OP's question, but since it gets to appear in search results for **declaring** multiple vars in a single line (which isn't possible at the moment). A cleaner way for that is:

```
var (
    n []int
    m string
    v reflect.Value
)
```