# Declare mutiple variables on the same line with types in Go

Tags: go

I have the below code snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var reader *bufio.Reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Enter your name")
    name, err := reader.ReadString('\n') //THIS LINE
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Hello " + name)
    }
}
```

My question is, if I want to NOT use the `:=` syntax (like I have at the first line of `main()`), how would I rewrite the `ReadString()` invocation with types?

I tried the following, with the corresponding errors:

1. `var name string, err error = reader.ReadString('\n')` -> `syntax error: unexpected comma at end of statement`
2. `var name, err string, error = reader.ReadString('\n')` -> `syntax error: unexpected comma at end of statement`
3. Taking a hint from [Multiple variables of different types in one line in Go (without short variable declaration syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086082/multiple-variables-of-different-types-in-one-line-in-go-without-short-variable) I also tried `var (name string, err error) = reader.ReadString('\n')` which also gives the same error.

For the above linked question, the marked answer simply suggests using two lines for two different variable types. But how would that work for the return values of a function like `ReadString()`?

Comment: `var name, err = reader.ReadString('\n')`? or why not just declare the variables upfront with `var` and specifying the type and using it afterwards?

Comment: `var name, err = reader.ReadString('\n')` does not make the type information obvious, the way `var reader *bufio.Reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)` makes it obvious that `reader` is of type `*bufio.Reader`. As for declaring the variables with type before, I can do that, but I would lose the one-line benefit. If you see the examples of what I've tried so far, maybe that would clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: I would compromise on the one line benefit, any day for better code readability.

Comment: It is not possible to explicitly declare two types in a single statement. A [variable spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) can have zero or one types.

Comment: I think this is a valid concern. You're welcome to submit a proposal for a new syntax to the Go language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all,

```
name, err := reader.ReadString('\n')`
```

is perfectly fine. Most IDE's will display you the types of the return values of `ReadString()` if you would not know them.

As the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086175/1705598) details, a variable declaration can have **one** optional type at most, so specifying 2 types is not possible.

If it bothers you that the types are not visible, that means **readability** is more important to you. If it is, break with that "one-liners-for-the-win" philosophy.

If you want the types to be visible in the source code, declare the types prior, and use assignment:

```
var (
    name string
    err  error
)
name, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
```

If you still need a one liner (*just for fun*), it requires a helper function. The name of the helper function can "state" the expected types:

```
func stringAndError(s string, err error) (string, error) {
    return s, err
}
```

Then you can use either a variable declaration or a short variable declaration:

```
var name, err = stringAndError(reader.ReadString('\n'))
// OR
name, err := stringAndError(reader.ReadString('\n'))
```