# Does Golang have something like C++'s decltype?

Tags: c++, go, introspection

C++ has `decltype(expr)`. You can declare an object of type of some other expression. For example:
`decltype('c') a[4]` will declare an array of 4 chars. This is a toy example, but this feature can be useful. Here is some Go code for a UDP server:

```golang
conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", udp_addr)
...
defer conn.Close()
...
_, err = conn.WriteToUDP(data, addr)
```

The important thing is that I know what I can *do* with the (type of the) result a function (in this case, with a connection, the result of `ListenUDP`), but I don't know what this type *is*. Here, because of Go's type inference, I don't need to know. But if I want to create 5 connections, then I'd like an array of 5 "results of `ListenUDP`". I am not able to do that. The closest I've got is:

```golang
ret_type := reflect.TypeOf(net.DialUDP)
first_param_type := reflect.TypeOf(ret_type.Out(0))
my_arr := reflect.ArrayOf(4, first_param_type)
my_arr[0] = nil
```

But the last line doesn't work. Is there a way to do it in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go does not have a compile-time equivalent to C++'s `decltype`.

But Go is a statically typed language: even though there's type inference in case of short variable declaration, the types are known at compile time. The result type(s) of [`net.ListenUDP()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#ListenUDP) are not visible in the source code, but you can look it up just as easily, e.g. it takes 2 seconds to hover over it with your mouse and your IDE will display the signature. Or check [online](https://pkg.go.dev/net#ListenUDP). Or run `go doc net.ListenUDP` in a terminal.

Signature of `net.ListenUDP()` is:

```
func ListenUDP(network string, laddr *UDPAddr) (*UDPConn, error)
```

So the array type to hold 5 of the returned connections is `[5]*net.UDPConn`. Also note that it's better and easier to use [slices](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types) instead of [arrays](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Array_types) in Go.

So instead I suggest to use a slice type `[]*net.UDPConn`. If you need a slice to hold 5 connections, you can make it using the builtin `make()` like this: `make([]*net.UDPConn, 5)`.

If you really need to do this dynamically, at runtime, yes, reflection can do this. This is how it could look like:

```
funcType := reflect.TypeOf(net.ListenUDP)
resultType := funcType.Out(0)
arrType := reflect.ArrayOf(4, resultType)
arrValue := reflect.New(arrType).Elem()

conn := &net.UDPConn{}
arrValue.Index(0).Set(reflect.ValueOf(conn))

fmt.Println(arrValue)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ZOa8ILqxQ3G)):

```
[0xc00000e058 <nil> <nil> <nil>]
```

See related: [Declare mutiple variables on the same line with types in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69518431/declare-mutiple-variables-on-the-same-line-with-types-in-go/69518670#69518670)

Comment: I see, thank you!
> but you can look it up just as easily, e.g. it takes 2 seconds to hover over it with your mouse and your IDE will display the signature. Or check online. Or run go doc net.ListenUDP in a terminal.

My problem was not really "I don't know the return type of ListenUDP", but I didn't know of the go doc <something>, that's useful.

On another note, I've not tried many IDEs (for Go), only VSCode. IMHO, the official extension is somewhat irritating, so I turned it off, and I have only the default syntax highlighting.